# gvim search query for mixed AND & OR conditions

Tags: search

Hi I want to search text inside gvim with the following criteria 
`a&b&(c|d)`.
I know for `a&b` it is `/.*a\&.*b` and for `c|d` it is `/c\|d` but combining these two doesnt work.
what can be the exact command ?

edit: I tried `.*a\&.*b\&.*(c\|d)`, but it is taking it as `.*a\&.*b\&.*(c` ORed with `d)` , inc brackets.

edit2: breaking the expression to `a&b&c`|`a&b&d` is working,`.*a\&.*b\&.*c\|.*a\&.*b\&.*d` , but thats not something I am looking for.

Comment: Can you provide some examples on what are you trying to do, i.e., a sample text and the expected matches for your (intended) regex? [(XY Problem)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/188334)

Comment: @mMontu ok. amm. for example, I want to search lines with following criteria,
USB & LENGTH should definitly be there along with either RX or TX.

Comment: `()` have to be escaped in Vim's regex to be used for grouping, `:help /\(`.  An unescaped `(` or `)` matches the literal character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `:help \&`:

```
2. A branch is one or more concats, separated by "\&".  It matches the last
   concat, but only if all the preceding concats also match at the same
   position.  Examples:
    "foobeep\&..." matches "foo" in "foobeep".
    ".*Peter\&.*Bob" matches in a line containing both "Peter" and "Bob"
```

> I want to search lines with following criteria, USB & LENGTH should
>   definitly be there along with either RX or TX.

So it seems impossible that any text would match "USB" AND "LENGTH". You would probably use something like:

```
\(USB.*LENGTH\).*\(RX\|TX\)
```

or, using `\v` to reduce the escaping:

```
\v(USB.*LENGTH).*(RX|TX)
```

If you meant USB and LENGTH but in any order:

```
\v(.*USB&.*LEN).*(RX|TX)
```

Comment: the last one, can you pls rewrite without using \v ? to correlate.

Comment: `\(.*USB\&.*LEN\).*\(RX\|TX\)` -- you can find the details in `:help \v`

Answer (score 4):

You may want to use `:logiPat`. It ships with newer versions of Vim.

```
:LogiPat "a"&"b"&("c"|"d")
```

For more help see: `:h logipat`

Comment: Is it part of vim, or an add-on ?
I am using vim7.4 and help didnt return anything.

this is the page of logipat,  
http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=1290

Comment: it's bundled with newer Vims, starting from something like 7.4.700 or so.